# OSX Audio Hijack style audio recording from other applications (cocoa)

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, recording

Hi basically I am lost in apples documentation and not sure where to start on this.

I need to record the audio from applications running on my system, similar to audio hijack and wiretap studio pro, but I am unsure where to start with the audio captuer.  I see reference to quicktime capture documentation but it is not clear how to acheive what I require.

Ideally I want to be able to modify audio in/out from an application such as skype to record and manipulate (think novelty voice effects).

Any pointers where in the documentation I can look, or how to start with this?

Answer (score 7):

I think you should take a look at the [Jack OS X](http://www.jackosx.com/) [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jackosx).
It has a CoreAudio user space driver that allows you to send any application's sound output to Jack OS X and support for audio plugins.