# How to steal audio from specific application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am trying to figure out how to capture the audio from a given software running on a mac, just like [audio hijack](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) does.

I'm aware that this is not the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965045/osx-audio-hijack-style-audio-recording-from-other-applications-cocoa) on the subject, but I'd like to better understand the possibilities on how to do it.
Crete a user space driver is the only solution to achieve it?

Comment: Audio Hijack did it by injecting a low-level audio library to replace the one Mac OS X normally uses. This approach does not work with signed applications, so I'm not sure how they do it now with Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2):

The best way that I've found is to get [soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) from [cycling74.com](http://cycling74.com/).  This basically gives your computer an internal interface that you can route to audio programs.  If you then get a DAW like audacity you can choose soundflower as your audio input, set soundflower as your system audio output and record audio directly into your DAW.

GW